# How to document with Doxygen: typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, EnumType)

Tags: objective-c, doxygen

Apple provides the `NS_ENUM` and `NS_OPTION` macros ([link to docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014150-CH1-SW6)) to define enumerations in Objective-C. Here's an example how this looks like for `NS_ENUM`:

```
--- EnumName.h ---

#pragma once
#import <Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h>

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, EnumName)
{
  EnumMemberA,
  EnumMemberB,
  EnumMemberC,
};
```

What is the syntax to write Doxygen documentation for such an enumeration type definition (and also for the enumeration members)?

At first I tried the intuitive thing: Write a `@brief` documentation block just before the definition.

```
--- EnumName.h ---

#pragma once
#import <Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h>

/// @file

/// @brief A brief description.
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, EnumName)
{
  EnumMemberA,
  EnumMemberB,
  EnumMemberC,
};
```

Result: Doxygen includes the documentation block in its generated output (✅), but parses the definition as a function (❌). Places where the enumeration type is used, such as in function/method arguments, are not linked (❌).

Next I tried adding an `@enum EnumName` command in front.

```
--- EnumName.h ---

#pragma once
#import <Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h>

/// @file

/// @enum EnumName
/// @brief A brief description.
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, EnumName)
{
  EnumMemberA,
  EnumMemberB,
  EnumMemberC,
};
```

Result: Doxygen issues this warning: `warning: Documentation for undefined enum 'EnumName' found` and does not include the documentation block in its generated output at all (❌).

I can understand that Doxygen may be unable to parse the `typedef NS_ENUM` construct, but in that case I would like to be able to write a documentation block decoupled from actual source code.

I'm using Doxygen 1.10.0, installed via Homebrew on macOS 13.5.2 on an Intel Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by changing Doxygen's preprocessor expansion settings:

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING  YES
MACRO_EXPANSION       YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF    YES
PREDEFINED            "NS_ENUM(enum_type,enum_name)=enum enum_name"
```

This changes the original definition

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, EnumName)
```

to look like this:

```
typedef enum EnumName
```

This is sufficiently good for the Doxygen parser so that regular documentation blocks can be written.